# Azure DevOp deploy websites under one master website

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-deployment, webdeploy

I have created new build pipeline for my Git project.
Release pipeline also created for same with CI/CD cycle.
I have total 10 api projects need to deployed to IIS,

I would like to deploy 9 api's under one master Api,
How do i do the same.

I am using IIS web app manage and IIS Web App Deploy task to deploy to IIS.

Comment: Please provide more context. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure DevOp deploy websites under one master website

We could not deploy one websites under another website, just could deploy web app under another web app.

[image]

We could only add the app under the website instead of the website. And based on the content of your question, it seems that your title is not accurate enough.

> I would like to deploy 9 api's under one master Api, How do i do the
> same.

If you want to deploy other 9 api's under one master Api, you could deploy those 9 api's under the same website on the `IIS web app manage` task:

[image]

And set the `Virtual Application` under the master Api App in the IIS Web App Deploy task：

[image]

The test result:

[image]